# C# implementing interface with events

Tags: c#, interface

I have and interface as shown below:

```cs
public delegate void ScriptFinished();

public interface IScript
{
    event ScriptFinished ScriptFinishedEvent;
}
```

Now I want to implement the interface as shown below:

```cs
public class Script : IScript
{
    event ScriptFinished ScriptFinishedEvent;
}
```

But I get error:

> 'Script.ScriptFinishedEvent' cannot implement an interface member because
>   it is not public.

Ok, I add `public` to the event:

```cs
public interface IScript
{
    public event ScriptFinished ScriptFinishedEvent;
}
```

But the error is:

> The modifier 'public' is not valid for this item

What I do wrong here and how can I implement an interface with events?

Comment: Put `public` into implementation, not into interface.

Comment: FYI Everything in an interface is public, so you cannot apply any access modifier to them, even public.

Comment: Seems like you missed the important parts of the error message. '**Script**.ScriptFinishedEvent' cannot **implement** an interface member because it is not public. - first the message clearly states it is talking about **Script** and not **IScript** and that the **implementation** is wrong.

Comment: Sidenote: I recommend you use [EventHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of your custom delegate. You can also use your custom EventArgs if needed ( [EventHandler<ScriptFinishedEventArgs>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db0etb8x(v=vs.110).aspx) )

Comment: @juharr, Everything in an interface is public ... for now. [C# 8 will likely change that by allowing modifiers](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/default-interface-methods.md).

Comment: @David argh ... the _one_ reason I was glad to be able to switch back to C# from Java ... :D

Comment: So strange ... I have not seen a community more aggressively than C# one. Almost all questions are downvoted.

Comment: @fobilis I also feel many downvotes should actually be close votes. But I don't see this being specific to C# questions.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Change:

```
public class Script : IScript
{
    event ScriptFinished ScriptFinishedEvent;
}
```

to:

```
public class Script : IScript
{
    public event ScriptFinished ScriptFinishedEvent;
}
```

> 'Script.ScriptFinishedEvent' cannot implement an interface member
>   because it is not public.

is referring to the `class`, not the `interface`.

Comment: Hah, now I see that. With declaring the implemented event as public that works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

An interface implementation has to be public:

```
public class Script : IScript
{
    public event ScriptFinished ScriptFinishedEvent;
}
```

However, you can hide it, if you want to restrict the access for a specific class. This is the closest you can get to making it private:

```
public class Script : IScript
{
    event IScript.ScriptFinished ScriptFinishedEvent;
}
```

In this case the `ScriptFinishedEvent` can still be accessed but you have to cast it to `IScript` first. (An example for this would be C#'s `Array.Add()` which implements `IList`)